# How do recursions continue calling after a return

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work out how this function operates,

```
function mergeSort(a) {
  if (a.length === 1) return a;
  const mid = Math.trunc(a.length / 2);
  const left = mergeSort(a.slice(0, mid));
  const right = mergeSort(a.slice(mid));
  const result = [];

  ((l, r) => {
    let i = 0,
      j = 0;

    while (i < l.length && j < r.length) {
      l[i] < r[j] ? result.push(l[i++]) : result.push(r[j++]);
    }
    while (i < l.length) result.push(l[i++]);
    while (j < r.length) result.push(r[j++]);
  })(left, right);

  return result;
}

const random = [10, 5, 2, 7, 3, 4];
```

I dont understand what is keeping the left side / right side in its memory.

on the first iteration the Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) has the parameters [5,2] because [1] was returned. It then sorts [5,2]. why then does the IIFE run again sorting left[10], right[2,5]? what causes this action?

Comment: Have you used your debugger to trace execution? If not, why not?

Comment: Which part of the function exactly is confusing you?
It might be a good idea to check out a merge sort visualization. It makes it easier to comprehend recursive algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont understand what is keeping the left side / right side in its memory

The left/right side is kept in the `left` and `right` variables for each function call. Since variables are function-scoped that means that each call can have their own version of `left` and `right`

Merge sort is a classic example of the "Divide and conquer" method. The input array is split into smaller and smaller fractions through recursion. The recursion happens until we're left with 1 element units.
After that it's just a matter of merging 2 sorted arrays on the way up out of the recursion.

There are very neat websites showcasing the visualization of algorithms. Take a look [at this website here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/merge-sort/visualize/)

Edit: As [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai) mentioned in his comment. Try to run this code through a debugger. It'll give you a better overview on how exactly your code runs line by line.

Edit 2:

```
((l, r) => {
    let i = 0,
      j = 0;

    while (i < l.length && j < r.length) {
      l[i] < r[j] ? result.push(l[i++]) : result.push(r[j++]);
    }
    while (i < l.length) result.push(l[i++]);
    while (j < r.length) result.push(r[j++]);
  })(left, right);
```

This code is what merges 2 sorted arrays and sorts them while merging.

The first while compares the first first element in the left side and the first in the right. It adds the smaller one to the results array and continues comparing.

After there's nothing left to compare (we've exhausted either of the lists) we just shove what remained of the other list into the results array.

Comment: "After that it's just a matter of merging 2 sorted arrays on the way up out of the recursion" this is whats confusing me, I dont understand where in the code allows for that?

Comment: I'm gonna edit my answer since I can format better there